# connection timed out error in running the app in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

When I run my node js app giving node app.js ,setting NODE_ENV = production , it is not getting set to production rather it gives the connection timed out error when I run the app.I want it actually get connected with mongolab Please waiting for your suggestions. Thank you in advance.

```
 C:\Users\Desktop\myapp>node app.js
    ChatBox working on port 3000
    Mode:development

    C:\Users\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\se
    rver.js:228
            process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                                ^
    Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
```

This is my app.js program

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
path =require('path'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
session = require('express-session'),
config = require('./config/config.js'),
ConnectMongo = require('connect-mongo')(session)
mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(config.dbURL)

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine' , 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images')));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.route('/').get(function(req,res,next){
//  res.render('index', {title:'Welcome to ChatBox'});
//})
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    if(env ==='development'){
        app.use(session({secret:config.sessionSecret,
                        saveUninitialized:true,
                        resave:true}))

    }
    else
    {
                app.use(session({
                secret:config.sessionSecret,
                saveUninitialized:true,
                        resave:true,
                store:new ConnectMongo({
                    url:config.dbURL,
                    stringify:true
                })

                }))

    }


    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        username:String,
        password:String,
        fullname:String
    })

    var Person = mongoose.model('users',userSchema);

    var Kajol= new Person({
        username:'Kajol',
        password:'kajol_123',
        fullname:'Kajol Sakshi'
    })

    Sunitha.save(function(err){
        console.log('done');
    })



require('./route/route.js')(express , app);
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('ChatBox working on port 3000');
    console.log("Mode:" +env);
})
```

my development.json

This is dummy URL .I didn't posted my original URL here.Just for format

```
{
        "dbURL" :"mongodb://chatboxuser:chatbox1234@ds051803.mongolab.com:41603/chatbox",
        "sessionSecret":"ALKKLHFDOI7UW98U3209UNFER923YH"


    }
```

Comment: How are you "setting NODE_ENV=production"? You should use: `set NODE_ENV=production && node app.js` to set the production mode for Node in Windows.

Comment: The timed out error happens both in production and development. But when I set production , it is not changing the mode as production and still in development and through the error.

Comment: I edited it and only uploaded ,its a dummy URL and do you have any idea about warning ??

Comment: Are you able to use the [`mongo`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/) command-line tool to connect to the sever?

Comment: Hello , No it shows Bson data error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that mongoose is not compiling properly, from the error messages sent earlier. By using this page https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

You'll notice on this page that node-gyp, the module which nodejs uses to compile modules to native code requires a few extra things like Visual Studio etc. See if you can download these and setup as instructed. Once you do that, then install node-gyp again, and re-install all dependencies including mongoose.

Generally speaking, this should get the job done as a last measure.